# Using JS to draw a horizontal rule

Tags: javascript, html

This might be a basic question, but how does one make a horizontal line (a.k.a horizontal rule) in Javascript, akin to the html `<hr>` tag? I want to be able to set its color and thickness, exactly like how the `<hr>` tag allows me.

I have a website where I need to do this inside a `<script`> tag (along with some accompanying code). I can't use `<hr>` since some of my users don't have JS enabled; so for them none of the `<script>` tag contents will show, but `<hr>` will still show (and I don't want that to happen).

Comment: Have you considered using a `<hr>` with a CSS `display: none;` inside a `<noscript>` block?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: apologies, I'm actually unaware of that. Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: I answered with a couple techniques in a sample. Generally speaking, I always try to write plain, simple HTML that works for what I want, then customize it later with javascript, css, or noscript elements to cover the special cases. Doing it that way tends to give readable source code and good compatibility - basic html works for virtually everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Tackling the problem, first:

> I can't use `<hr>` since some of my users don't have JS enabled; so for them none of the `<script>` tag contents will show, but `<hr>` will still show (and I don't want that to happen).

You can add a class to your `<html>` element in JavaScript (with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) if you don’t need IE 9 support):

```
document.documentElement.className += ' has-js';
```

then style your `<hr>` not to appear unless JavaScript is supported:

```
<hr class="hey-that’s-my-line" />
```

```css
.hey-that’s-my-line {
    display: none;
    /* change its height & colour here */
}

html.has-js .hey-that’s-my-line {
    display: block;
}
```

Now, answering your question: you can create elements and insert them into your document using the DOM API. It’s a bit much to cover entirely in this answer, but MDN has [a good introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

```
var hr = document.createElement('hr');

document.body.appendChild(hr); // inserts it at the end of <body>;
                               // appendChild() inserts at the end of any node,
                               // generally

var ref = document.getElementById('reference-point');

ref.parentNode.insertBefore(hr, ref); // inserts it before the element
                                      // with the id 'reference-point'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just create an HR element on a page using javascript, it's as follows:

```
 elem = document.createElement("hr"); //this will create a new element

 /* Use setAttribute to define the property and values you'd like give the element */

   elem.setAttribute("width", "100px");

/* Then you'll need to add the element to the page */

 document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: The question says that JS isn't available for some users.

Comment: @Ryan Ah, I misunderstood the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard `<hr>` element with some CSS to hide it from noscript users.

Take a look at this: http://arsdnet.net/testo.html with and without javascript. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Noscript example</title>
        <style>
                /* this css is used by people with and without javascript */
                /* a <link> tag would work as well, of course */
        </style>
        <noscript>
                <style>
                        /* this is only visible by people without JS enabled */
                        hr {
                                display: none;
                        }
                </style>
        </noscript>
        <script>
                /* And this script only runs with JS (obviously) so by adding
                   a class name to the root element (<html>), we can also detect
                   it in CSS....
                */
                document.documentElement.className += " with-js";
        </script>
        <style>
                /* ...meaning we can target it with CSS like this too: */
                html.with-js hr {
                        color: red;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        Hi, before hr
        <hr />
        After hr
</body>
</html>
```

The `<noscript>` tag is valid HTML from waaaaay back and works everywhere. Anything inside it is visible only to people without script support, and it can hold any content: fallback html, link tags, style tags, anything.

By putting a style tag in it, I can use CSS to hide elements I don't want non-script users to see.

So then I just write normal HTML below it which will be visible normally to all users - nothing special there. Then, using the `<noscript><style>` I modify it for people without script as a special case.

Sometimes btw, you want to only show things to script users, instead of only hide things from nonscript users. The easiest way to do that is to stick a class on your html element using javascript, then target that class name descendants with CSS. The next few lines in the sample show that. Again, you write normal HTML, then modify it after the fact, but this time with a combination of `<script>` to add a class and `<style>` to target it.

So looking at this page with JS, you will see a red hr. Without JS, the hr will not appear.